# JDiameter issue with Cisco Diameter server

Tags: java, mobicents, restcomm

I have some issue, which looks strange to me. Could you have a look into?

I'm trying to send CER message to our Cisco diameter server. According to log file, which I'm getting, CER is received from Cisco side and CEA was replied back to my jdiameter client. For some reason, jdiameter client is not able to process

it in right way and keep trying to send CER (my listener is never called back). Please look at in attached log file, configuration of my jdiameter client and source code. My jdiameter client is very simple and straightforward.

Configuration of Java client: http://textuploader.com/a2mn2

Log file: http://textuploader.com/a2mnn

Thanks,

Comment: Code of Java Client:

http://textuploader.com/a2mnf

Answer (score -1):

You need to add your listener to a Network object so listener callback can be called when a message comes.

You can see an example [here](https://github.com/RestComm/jdiameter/blob/master/examples/charging-server-simulator/src/main/java/org/mobicents/servers/diameter/charging/ChargingServerSimulator.java).